# msysgit path issues

Tags: git

I've got one problem regarding msysgit.

My git work dir is say, at C:\sw\work.git.
My source is at "C:\sw\work.git\src\myfile.h".

I've used both command prompt and bash prompt from msysgit.
Somehow, I have ended up with this issue (I cannot recall how):
both "C:/sw/work.git/src/myfile.h" and "src/myfile.h" are 
in my repository. The first path is not my intention at all. Whenever I made changes
to myfile.h, I've got mysterious modification notices in both files since essentially
they are the same file with two different name.

Any merging, update or rebase operation becomes entangled with these
paths and stopped half-way.

Is there any way to resolve this issue? At least removing hardcoded path
out of my repository and leaving relative path only?

Comment: At first, it sounds like you're using a bare repo. What does `git status` and `git log` tells you? Have you initialized the directory yourself or cloned from anywhere?

Comment: No it's not a bare repo. Just a sample name only. Don't be fooled by the ".git" extension. The problem definition is extracted from a real situation involving two ssh-connected PCs with one central bare server, two work directories. The problem is spread across multiple branches since I've merged occasionally across them. But I think as long as one branch is solved, it can be solved in other branches as well since all work directories and central server are used by me alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try cloning again your `C:\sw\work.git` (`git clone --no-hardlinks C:\sw\work.git C:\anotherPath`), and see if the issue persists with that new repo.
(The '`--no-hardlinks`' option shouldn't matter with Windows, but it is just to be on the safe side)

Comment: The clone also has the same problem.